# Angular2 install external module in system.config.js

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to use an external module in my code, I have followed the instructions but cannot seem to get anywhere as it seems it cannot find the module.
I am just using the standard Angular2 set up with a system.js file with my modules in. I have got it working with ng2-bootstrap which is an external module. The difference here is that it has a .js file where as this extension does not. It's just typescript files.

The extension is: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-money-mask

here is my system.config.js file:

```
app: 'app',
      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      '@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',
      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
      'core-js-shim':              'npm:core-js/client/shim.min.js',
      'zone':                      'npm:zone.js/dist/zone.js',
      'reflect':                   'npm:reflect-metadata/Reflect.js',
      'ng2-http-interceptor':      'npm:ng2-http-interceptor/dist/http/http-interceptor.js',
      'lodash' :                   'node_modules/lodash/lodash.js',
      'moment':                   'node_modules/moment/moment.js',
      'ng2-bootstrap': 'node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/bundles/ng2-bootstrap.umd.min.js'
```

Comment: Have you done `npm install ng2-money-mask --save`?

Comment: I read about a map function in system.js where you can map file with its extension can you try to do that ?

Comment: Yes I have run the install

Comment: // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        packages: {
            app: {
                main: './main.ts',
                defaultExtension: 'ts'
            },
            rxjs: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        } you can try to add the package file like this